# Resolve 'undefined reference' to a global external array variable

Tags: c, extern, undefined-reference

I have a header `constants.h` file, with the following declarations of an array variable:

```
extern storageCommandData storageCommands[];
```

The type of the array is defined elsewhere, and is not relevant to the question.
In another source file (.c) I initialized the array like so:

```
#include "constants.h"

storageCommandData storageCommands[STORAGE_COMMAND_NUM] =
    {
        /*storageCommandData intilazation follows the
          following template: {commandName, storageSize}*/
        {".db", 1},
        {".dw", 4},
        {".dh", 2},
        {".asciz", 0},
};
```

I tried to use these arrays in another source file (a different one than the one I define the arrays in), by including `constants.h`.

However, when I try to use the variable storageCommands I get the following error message:

```
undefined reference to `storageCommands'
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: When linking, did you include the source or object file containing the definition of `storageCommands`?  Please show the command lines you used to compile and link, or otherwise explain your build process.

Comment: Including the .h file in the other file is not enough. You need to link it with the object file containing that array

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) first.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer. I didn't link the source file that defined the arrays when I compiled

Comment: The name "constants.h" sees to promise something you may not be delivering (unless the typedef `storageCommandData` includes a `const` qualifier).  If it is not truly a `const` then being global is a bad idea:  https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/

Answer (score 1):

Using `extern` means that you are using a variable that is declared in another *translation unit* (i.e. basically a source file and the headers it includes). It is the *linker*'s task to relate the `extern`-specified variable name to its actual declaration. If the linker cannot find the latter, it will report an "undefined reference".

As already pointed out in the comments, the most common cause of this error is that the source file containing the actual declaration was not compiled or linked.